# Fingerprint scanner in my HP Probook is not working

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in my HP probook 440 G6 which has an in-built fingerprint scanner but it does not work.

**Settings > User > Authentication and Login** is showing no option for fingerprint. What to do?

Comment: What you're looking for is `libfprint` and your device may not yet be implemented. You can check [here](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html) and the project is located [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint).

Comment: Failed to activate fingerprint scanner in my HP notebook!!

Comment: Did u solve this @MohammadAbulHasnat