# ubuntu HP probook 450 G8 fingerprint not showing in settings

Tags: 20.04, hp, scanner, fingerprint-reader

I'm new to ubuntu. I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64 bit.GNOME 3.36.8.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264922/fingerprint-scanner-in-my-hp-probook-is-not-working) question similar to my problem.

so I tried to use [this project freedesktop / libfprint](https://github.com/freedesktop/libfprint) and successfully build and compiled but am not sure about the next step.

How can I enable this now?

any help would be greatly appreciated.
screenshot attached.

[image]